# Sorting results by a char(1) column

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I have a stored procedure which basically does something like

```
select top 1 expiryDate, flag, (bunch of other columns)
from someTable
(bunch of joins)
order by expiryDate desc
```

So this will grab the record that expires last. This works for most cases, except some records have a flag that are just a `char(1)`. Most of the time it's just `Y` or `N`.

So it'll return something like

```
2010-12-31    N
2010-10-05    Y
2010-08-05    N
2010-03-01    F
2010-01-31    N
```

This works, most of the time, but is there any way to order it by the Flag column as well? So I'd want to group the results by `Y`, then `N`, and `F` and any other flags can go last in any order. I thought this would just be an order by, but since the flags are not weighted by the alphabetic value, I'm a little stumped. (Note: These are not my tables, I don't know if using the characters like this was a good idea or not, but it's not something I can change).

Comment: So you want to tie break equal expiryDate values with the flag?

Comment: @gbn, it's unlikely the expiryDates will be equal (if it matters), but yes. I'd want the one flagged "Y" before any of the others.

Comment: So this is the question: secondary sort/tie break? The TOP 1 gives latest expiryDate that's all, but the question emphasises flags and groupings

Comment: @gbn, secondary seems right. The flags and grouping is just so that the ones marked 'Y' will always be taken if one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the help of a CASE statement

```
Order By expiryDate desc, 

   CASE flag
      When 'Y' THEN 1
      When 'N' THEN 2
      When 'F' THEN 3
      ELSE 999
   END ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can order by several columns:

```
select top 1 expiryDate, flag, (bunch of other columns)
from someTable
(bunch of joins)
order by flag /* asc/desc */, expiryDate desc
```